# Rigid registration of multiple 3D bodies

Tags: optimization, rigid-transformation

Let's assume I have $N$ 3d bodies and I want to register them with a rigid transformation (Rotation and translation). To simplify the problem, let's assume that we are only looking for a rotation. In this case we are looking for an orthogonal matrix for each body $R_{i}$.

Between each pair of bodies ${i,j}$, We have a set of point matches. The matches between two bodies i and j are $X_{i}^{j}$ (points in body i that match j) and $X_{j}^{i}$ (corresponding points in body j).

For the case N = 2, there is an analytical solution to this problem: https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf . I tried to follow the same approach as and I found that the is minimizing the following quantity:

$$ - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  <R_{i} X_{i}^{j}, R_{j} X_{j}^{i}> $$

But I don't see where to go from here. I tried to use the lagrange multiplier but I didn't get anything. How would you proceed ?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to ignore the rigidity of the bodies and assume an affine transformation. The equations are purely linear and can be solved by least-squares (or with just 4 point correspondences). Furthermore, the system decomposes in three systems of four equations in four unknowns. Next, you can orthogonalize the matrix by Gram-Schmidt if you like.

Comment: How do you solve it by least squares? The problem is that $Y$ Also varies depending on the transformation of its body.

Comment: Take a look a gtsam, I believe you should be able to tailor it to your purposes. Note that you need to fix one of the R's, to eliminate global rotation ambiguity.